# Stop-and-Wait ARQ algorithm

Tags: protocol-theory

In the Stop-and-Wait algorithm, the sender needs to re-transmit the frame if the acknowledgement received is corrupted during transmission. But just the fact that the sender received an acknowledgement from the receiver means that the frame was received. Why does it matter whether it is corrupted or not? Why is there a need to re-transmit?

Comment: Any corrupted transmission cannot be trusted for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But just the fact that the sender received an acknowledgement from the
>   receiver means that the frame was received.

That statement is just not true since a negative acknowledgement means that the sent frame was damaged or a duplicate, and the sender must resend the frame.

There are both positive and negative acknowledgements. If the acknowledgement is corrupt, it can't be trusted, and it is considered a negative acknowledgement, forcing the frame to be resent.